# BSOD when modifying an XPage

Tags: eclipse, xpages, bsod

I have a very weird situation. Since a few days, the following actions will crash my Windows 10 PC (using Notes R9.01FP8):

- I open my Prefs page in the Domino Designer
- click on the Source tab
- move to a specific location in a table
- then I add a Repeat control
- I then open the Properties of the Repeat control
- to set the data to JavaScript...

and nothing happens, until after a few seconds: BSOD - Unexpected Kernel Mode Trap in either win32kfull.sys or ntoskrnl.exe.

Sometimes, the JavaScipt box is displayed, so I can paste my code, but a short while later the PC still crashes.

I have to say that my PC crashed a lot lately, so I reinstalled Windows and all drivers, so there might be a rotten one that causes all this. According to DriverEasy, all drivers are now up to date. The Event viewer displays a BugCheck event, but nothing relevant (to me anyway).

What I did for further analysis:

- I removed Cache.ndk, it didn't help (of course)
- in a copy of the XPage, the system crashes when I add the Repeat
- ditto, in a different XPage
- it seems to work in a different Notes database, on a different XPage
- so I created a new database, copied all elements from the original database over, and still the system crashes when I add the Repeat

I'll be doing so more tests, e.g. with an empty database and just one XPage, then adding my Prefs page, or with the same database but then on a server. Actually, one could say I'm kind of lost, and stumbling around  in the dark.

My questions to the XPages/Eclipse gurus:

- could it be the workspace, and is there any way to reset it?
- do you have any suggestions how to get this solved?

Thanks!

Comment: Just did a test with a brand new database, new XPage, added a Repeat Control, then in Properties, set DataSource to JavaScript, and it crashed.

Comment: Could it be the Windows 10 Creators Update bug that crashes Notes in certain scenarios?

Comment: If you are running Windows 10 Creators Update then make sure to install this fix: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4022716/windows-10-update-kb4022716

Comment: Will do, thanks! Didn't know that there was (one more) bug... ;-)

Comment: This seems to be the one: "Addressed issue (Error 0x7F) with Windows Forms (WinForms) that causes the system to crash after upgrading to the Creators Update." I hope the update comes down with the cumulative update that's currently being downloaded (KB40225342). Otherwise I'll have to download the whole caboodle (745Mb). Thanks again!

Comment: I hope it helps! If so, I'll add my comment as an answer

Comment: @Per Henrik: I'll probably never know whether the fix you mentioned would have helped. The one I was downloading (KB4025342) seems to have helped in that the system didn't crash (that's the good news) but the Properties tab isn't fully functional yet (which is the sad news), at least during my first tests. When I click the JavaScript radio button, the text box doesn't always show up. A copy/paste of some value="javascript:..." parameter does help, the box then opens. I'll do more tests tomorrow. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Creator update that MS posted does not seem to fix the Designer crash. 
https://grahamacres.wordpress.com/2017/07/10/domino-designer-still-crashes-after-windows-10-creators-update/

Comment: A partial fix is to use the source pane to add your value property. That seems to help.

Comment: That might work, but you'd better not use/open the Properties tab at the same time. I think that displaying the radio button and/or the text-box somehow plays havoc with the Windows internals. Better use the newer upgrade!! And hope there will be another one that fixes the fix...

Comment: More info. - MS does have a fix, you just have to be careful to make sure that it gets installed. https://grahamacres.wordpress.com/2017/07/12/windows-10-crash-using-domino-designer-there-is-a-fix/

Comment: I can confirm that KB4025342 seems to help (I'm careful!). I now have Version 1703 OS Build 15063.483 and my system didn't crash. No guarantees for the future...

Comment: Funny things still happening: the Event tab isn't visible ("no events specified"), or doesn't work correctly.

Comment: I uninstalled KB4025342, downloaded and installed KB4022716: no improvement. I can't save a modified XAgent, for the Script radio button shows an empty screen. If I change my code on the Source tab, saving the XPage doesn't work, the Modified date in the properties still indicate yesterday. Creators Update? My creativity is put on hold!